# New owner of phone and I need to get admin access!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, factory-reset

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII that I got from work. When I got it it was on a vodafone plan and linked to the work gmail account. I left the company but bought the phone off them, returning the sim card.

My new sim works fine, but the phone seems tied to the old email account. I can't update many of my apps as I am prompted to enter the password for the work email account which I dont have! When I try to remove that email it says I cant as it is required by some apps and I will need to do a factory reset.

Is there any other way I can get control over the phone? If not what will I need to save before doing the factory reset? Im not fussed about reinstalling apps but should I save all my pictures etc first?

Comment: Welcome to the site! The good news is that it should be pretty trivial to get your factory reset done. It's always good to back up any pictures, videos, and other personal data before a factory reset. Do you happen to know the model number of your phone? (Something like `Galaxy SII i9100`)

Comment: Could you check whether some *Device Administrator* is active? To me that sounds like you had some Exchange mail account with the company, which usually requires *their* profiles being activated on your device – and that's done via *Device Admin*. You should find that in *Settings→Security*.

Comment: dotVezz: Thanks for the welcome :-) I cant see a model number on the phone, where would I find it? Izzy: I dont think Device Administrator is active, the only option in that section is to activate Android Device Manage and that is currently not activated as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Is that an Exchange email? Then YES, removing it will trigger a Factory Reset. This is standard operating procedure, for security purposes (of the company).

As [dotVezz](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/38018/dotvezz) said, you should back-up all your data (pictures, documents, downloaded files, etc). To back-up your apps and its data, you can use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en); needs ROOT. *Just to be on the safe side, also copy the Titanium folder (contains apps and data) to your PC.* After doing a Factory Reset, just restore the files with Titanium Backup (which you'd need to download from Google Play after the Factory Reset).